# C++ mmap of a set

Tags: c++, multithreading, set, fork, mmap

I have a C++ program in which I use fork(), but I need to be able to share an object which can be read and written to between the parent process and its children. From my reading online, it seems like mmap is the way to do this. Here is what I have:

```
enum messageType {New = 0, Old = 1, No_Message = 2};

typedef struct {
    enum messageType type;
    unsigned int senderID;
    char message[100];
} StoredMessageData;

struct StoredMessage {
    unsigned int recipientID;
    vector<StoredMessageData> messages;

    StoredMessage(const unsigned int& intRecipient = 0, const vector<StoredMessageData>& data = vector<StoredMessageData>())
    : recipientID(intRecipient), messages(data)
    {
        messages.reserve(10);
    }

    bool operator<(const StoredMessage& compareTo) const
    {
        return recipientID < compareTo.recipientID;
    }

    bool operator==(const StoredMessage& compareTo) const
    {
        return recipientID == compareTo.recipientID;
    }
};
```

Then in main:

```
set<StoredMessage> * msgs;
msgs  = mmap(NULL, sizeof(set<StoredMessage>), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
```

and later in main I use fork().

My question has 2 parts:

1) A set is of variable size, and I already know that in each forked process, I am going to want to be able to add a StoredMessage and add a StoredMessageData to the vector in StoredMessage. However, I am unsure that mmap can handle this... doesn't it just allocate enough space for the base object? Can I cause it to allocate enough to allow me to make these additions?

2) The above code from main is currently throwing an error:

error: invalid conversion from âvoid*â to âstd::set, std::allocator >*â

Does anyone know what this means/how to fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't want to be discouraging or anything, but if you can't answer these question by yourself you probably shouldn't be doing this. And actually no, this won't work.

Comment: I apologize if they're actually simple questions; I don't usually program in C++. However, in the interest of learning, posing a useful answer rather than a demeaning one might be more helpful in the future.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you are not even realizing what the actual issues with this approach are. And you obviously don't have a grasp of C++ fundamentals. And again the answer is "This won't work".

Comment: And what I'm saying is that your responses above are erroneous... they give me no idea as to why this won't work that I might be able to use constructively to actually learn anything nor do they offer anything that I might look into that might work better. As I said, I am not a C++ programmer and do not claim to to have any deep knowledge of C++, which obviously, from the apparent stupidity of my questions, I don't. However, I'm not learning anything or getting any better at using C++ from your snarky comments.

Comment: I'm sorry but if "this won't work" isn't good enough for you, go ahead and pay for a C++ course. Also you can ponder on why I'm the only one who even took the time to reply to this question.

Comment: Do you have to `fork()`? It might be easier to use threads if you want to share data anyway...

Comment: @GossamerShadow, remember that `std::set` is more than just the `std::set` object itself; there are numerous other bits of memory allocated behind the scenes by `std::set` for its tree nodes etc. You'd have to use placement new and custom `std::allocator` to ensure the set as well as all its internal data structures fit in a preallocated shared memory segment, as well as take care of synchronization. Why not use the filesystem instead (set=directory, key=filename)? Or have the parent manage the set and the child send set read/write commands to the parent via pipe?

Answer (score 0):

The STL classes std::vector<> and std::set<> allocate memory using operator new().
Operator new() allocates memory from the process heap.
The heap is not in shared memory, so anything allocated by one process can not be accessed by the other process.

You have a couple of choices.  First is to make a std::allocator<> that allocates from shared memory.

Second (and my preference) is to not use any objects in shared memory that use pointers.
This pretty much eliminates anything from STL.

You will also need a mutex to control access to the shared data so the two processes
do not corrupt your shared data.

Comment: What you are saying here has already been covered in the question comments above, and then some more; please consider adding additional detail, references, relevant examples etc. for your post to add tangible value. You may also want to explore alternatives (again, in more detail than the comments.)